# Need help creating a Model and migration for Tag model for Post model (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a *Post* model and I would like to create a *Tag* model so that posts can have tags (more than one at a time). I want to be able to search a post's tags and search posts tagged as X.

This is what I've realized so far in order to make this work (correct me if I'm wrong):

1. The *Tag* model only needs a `:name` attribute and the *Post* model needs a `:tag_list` attribute)
2. The *Post* and *Tag* must have either `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `many-to-many` associations between them (not sure which one).

I have no idea about the view or the form or how separating tags with a coma or a space will tun into separate tags that belong to the post.

Any suggestions or insights (with examples if possible).

Answer (score 1):

A few recommendations:

1. I think you'll need a join table as well, something like posts_tags or posts_to_tags, that
   has a tag_id and a post_id.
2. There's [a pretty good example](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Many-to-many) of the difference between many-to-many and HABTM in the AR docs. In this case, I'd use the HABTM because your join table doesn't have any meaningful characteristics (unlike the example, where "Assignment" is a first-class model).
3. Going from comma-delimited string to separate tags should probably be done with a before_save filter or something -- not sure there's built-in behavior here.

You could also look into the tagging gems listed on [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_tagging.html) if you're not doing this for learning purposes.

Comment: Well, its not for learning but I need more flexibility. For instance, I need to play with the Tag model rb file because users will be able to follow tags. The best plugin is `acts_as_taggable_on` but it never generated any model file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use has_many :through association. This is one of the best solution to your situation.

There is a detailed tutorial on Rails Guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association